# Archive - Show Page Month Headers

Tags: wp-query, pagination, date-query

Trying to output posts on an archive page with date titles. Ideally this can be a single query so I can paginate the archive. Currently I can call multiple queries for each date item but I don't think this will allow for pagination.

First the structure:

This Week
(Posts here)

Last Week
(Posts here)

June
(Posts here)

May
(Posts here)

April
(Posts here)

..

For instance if I want to paginate every 20 posts and I have 15 posts from this week and 10 in the last week, I would want to start page 2 with the posts from last week.

My current code can loop through the months, but not paginate:

```
    <?php

    // echo 'current: '.date('F Y').'<br />';

    $start = $month = strtotime(date('F Y'));
    $end = strtotime('2010-01-01');

    /*
    echo $start . '<br>';
    echo $end;
    */


    while($month > $end)
    {
         echo '<h3>'.date('F Y', $month), PHP_EOL.'</h3>';

                    $box_post_args = array(
                        'post_type'         => 'post',
                        'paged'             => $paged,
                        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                        'category__in' => $vet_category,
                        'date_query'     => array(
                                array(
                                'year'  => date('m', $month), PHP_EOL,
                                'month' => date('Y', $month), PHP_EOL
                                )
                            )
                    );

        // OUTPUT POSTS CONTENT HERE


         $month = strtotime("-1 month", $month);
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach in the end. I just called a single query and added the logic to check the date of the last post was in a different month:

```
            $today = date("r");
            $articledate = get_the_time('r');
            $difference = round((strtotime($today) - strtotime($articledate))/(24*60*60),0);


                if ($month_sort == true && ($difference <= 7) && $current_week == null) {
                    $vpost_count = 0;
                    echo '</h3><div class="clear"></div><h3>This Week</h3><div class="clear"></div>';
                    $current_week = 'set'; 

                }
                elseif ($month_sort == true && $current_month != get_the_date('F') && $difference >= 7) {
                    $vpost_count = 0;
                    echo '</h3><div class="clear"></div><h3>'.get_the_date('F').'</h3><div class="clear"></div>'; 
                    $current_month = get_the_date('F');
                }
```